# Why ajax doesn't work with POST method?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a button with `onclick="sendNews()"` and a PHP script which does the database work.
The problem is that the `$_POST` array is empty when `sendNews` runs.

Javascript:

```
function sendNews()
{
    var title=document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
    var body=document.getElementById("boddy").innerHTML;
    var params="title="+title+"&body="+body;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //Send the proper header information along with the request    
    xmlhttp.open("POST","sendnews.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("newsAddResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }     
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("../inc/functions.php");
if(!loginCheck())
    header('Location: index.php');

$title=@$_POST['title'];
$body=@$_POST['body'];
var_dump($_POST);
$q=sprintf("insert into `news`(`id`,`title`,`body`,`time`) values(NULL,'%s','%s','%s')",$title,$body,jgmdate('l jS F Y h:i:s A'));
mysql_query($q) or die("خطا".mysql_error());
echo "با موفقیت ارسال شد";

?>
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Your code looks ok at a first glance, so it's more a question about the things we don't see/know? What is the content of `params`? What kind of elements are `#title` and `#boddy`? If they are form elements, you'd probably want `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: If you amend your `sendnews.php` to dump the `$_POST` contents to a file, is it still blank?

Comment: Incidentally, you're requesting the `.innerHTML` of an object named `boddy` -- is that a typo or intentional?

Comment: yes var_dump($_POST) gives me an empty array , I don't know who and why gave me that negative score, but the params is set in the javascript code , line 4. thank you

Comment: the boddy is the div I named ,

Comment: it worked with GET method but the URL character limit was the problem of GET

Comment: I think you might need to prepare the request header before you `send()`, e.g: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Are there any errors messages in the server logs?

Comment: Also make sure you escape the data you sent with `encodeURIComponent`. And I see that you set `params`, but we cannot see the values of `title` and `body`. That's why I asked for an example of `param`'s content. You probably got the downvote because although you provided your code, there is not enough information to help you. And we don't like guessing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to correct errors in the code and to make it compatible with more browsers.
 Thanks to @Mr. BeatMasta   and   @Felix Kling   for setting me straight on placement of onreadystatechange, sending the header, and browser compatibility issues.

.
Javascript:

```
function sendNews()
{
    var title=document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
    var body=document.getElementById("boddy").innerHTML;

    var params="title="+title+"&body="+body;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //Send the proper header information along with the request    
    xmlhttp.open("POST","sendnews.php",true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("newsAddResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }     
    }

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

In your php you have:

```
$title=@$_POST['title'];
$body=@$_POST['body'];
```

That should be:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
```

Comment: "2) You should provide the onreadystatechange function before open and send." you're only constructing a JS object, so you don't have to specify onreadystatechange callback before open

Comment: ROFL xDDD you changed it not to be understood, but because you just corrected it))) you clearly wrote "BEFORE OPEN", not before the "REQUEST" :P

Comment: I don't think `FormData` is available in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Ok figured it out.. To send a POST request using ajax you need to set a urlencoded header, just put after xmlhtt.open()

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

the other code parts are correct as I've checked on my own

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)? It'll make your life a lot easier.

```
$('#your-send-button').click(function() {
    $.post('sendnews.php', {
        title: $('#title').html(),
        body: $('#boddy').html()
    }, function(data) {
        $('#newsAddResult').html(data);
    });
});
```